# python 3 get specific value from json dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-requests

I have a dictionary I'm getting from an API call. I am trying to grab a specific value from the results.

```
names = requests.get("http://some.api")
```

The result of that call when printed looks like this

```
{'mynames': [{'id': 38, 'name': 'Betsy'}, {'id': 93, 'name': 'Pitbull'}, {'id': 84, 'name': 'Liberty'}]}
```

I've tried the code below just to grab the result with 'Pitbull' as its name

```
filtered_names = {k:v for (k,v) in names.items() if "Pitbull" in v}
```

I get an error of

```
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'items'
```

How can I just grab a specific value from the data that is being pulled from the API call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`requests.get` gives a `'Response'` object rather than a `dict`. Only the latter has an `items` method for iteration.

You can use the `json` library to retrieve a regular Python dictionary:

```
import json
import requests

names = requests.get("http://some.api")
d = json.loads(names.text)
```

Then note you have a dictionary with one key where the value is a list of dictionaries. So you need to access `d['mynames']` to retrieve in-scope dictionaries via a *list* comprehension.

```
filtered_names = [el for el in d['mynames'] if 'Pitbull' in el['name']]

# [{'id': 93, 'name': 'Pitbull'}]
```

Comment: What do you see for `names.text`?

Comment: if i just print k using for k, v in d.items() only 'mynames' get printed

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
names = requests.get('https://api')
Json = json.loads(names)

filtered_names = {k:v for k,v in Json.items() if "Pitbull" in v}
```

Now one question in our mind must come what does this json.py do?
Well for Answer to this question you can refer  [enter link description here](https://realpython.com/python-json/)

Hope this doesn't throw `AttributeError`